# Working with DateTime as StringProperty

Tags: javafx-2, tableview

I have defined a DateTime field as StringProperty in my model to display date. I have few rows where the date column is empty in database and have defined a cellfactory to display the date in a desired format & blank for empty rows. My problem starts when i try to update one of those empty columns. The new date doesnt appear. It works for the rows where there is already a date value present.

Part of cellfactory:

```
txtfld.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                if(txtfld.getText().length() == 0) {
                    commitEdit(null);
                } else {
                    commitEdit((new DateTime(txtfld.getText(),"dd/MM/yyyy")).toString());
                }
            } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                cancelEdit();
            }
        }
    });
```

And the part where I am updating the model:

```
col_Purchase_DT.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Purchase, String>>() {
        @Override 
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<Purchase, String> tbl) {
             (tbl.getTableView().getItems().get(tbl.getTablePosition().getRow())).setDOB(tbl.getNewValue());
       }
   });
```

I have figured it out that after updating the empty cell with a date col_Purchase_DT.setOnEditCommit() is not called. But is works for non-empty cell. I am using JodaTime for datetime.

[image]

I cannot update the second row. But it works perfectly for first & third row.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be doing way too much coding for this. There's a TextFieldTableCell class that you can use for creating editable cells, and it handles all the wiring for you. Here's an example, based on the usual example from the tutorial. I used the Java 8 java.time.LocalDate for the date column, but the same idea can be applied for JodaTime (I'm just not familiar with the API).

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class TableWithEditableDateColumn extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        final TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = createTableColumn("firstName", "First Name", String.class);
        final TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = createTableColumn("lastName", "Last Name", String.class);
        final TableColumn<Person, LocalDate> birthdayCol = createTableColumn("birthday", "Birthday", LocalDate.class);

        final DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

        firstNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        lastNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        birthdayCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<LocalDate>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(LocalDate t) {
                if (t==null) {
                    return "" ;
                } else {
                    return dateFormat.format(t);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public LocalDate fromString(String string) {
                try {
                    return LocalDate.parse(string, dateFormat);
                } catch (DateTimeParseException exc) {
                    return null ;
                }
            }

        }));

        final ObservableList<Person> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", LocalDate.parse("14/03/1975", dateFormat)),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", LocalDate.parse("27/09/1982", dateFormat)),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", null),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", LocalDate.parse("12/07/1979", dateFormat)),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", LocalDate.parse("19/10/1984", dateFormat))
        );
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, birthdayCol);
        table.setItems(data);
        table.setEditable(true);

        final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(table);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <T> TableColumn<Person, T> createTableColumn(String property, String title, Class<T> type) {
        TableColumn<Person, T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(property));
        col.setEditable(true);
        col.setPrefWidth(100);
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final StringProperty firstName ;
        private final StringProperty lastName ;
        private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthday ;

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, LocalDate birthday) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName", firstName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName", lastName);
            this.birthday = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "birthday", birthday);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String value) {
            firstName.set(value);
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String value) {
            lastName.set(value);
        }

        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public LocalDate getBirthday() {
            return birthday.get();
        }

        public void setBirthday(LocalDate value) {
            birthday.set(value);
        }

        public ObjectProperty birthdayProperty() {
            return birthday;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: James_D what you have suggested is the simplest form. My Date TableCell requires more than just a StringConverter. I used TextFieldTableCell on a string column and the result was same. The problem here was not the editing tablecell but the model stringproperty and how it stored NULL values coming from database. I replaced the incoming NULL with "" and it started working. Now while writing the values back to database instead of NULL it writes "" in the table.

Comment: That sounds like your custom cell implementation isn't properly handling null values; though I would expect a stack trace with a NullPointerException somewhere.

Comment: As I told the problem is not with the custom cell factory. It happens with your provided code also.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're asking then. My code example actually stores a null value and handles it fine: editing from a null value to a non-null one, and vice versa, works as expected. I tested changing the initialization of one of the String values to null too, and that worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

onEditCommit is not fired if an update happens on a null value.

Here is the answer: http://www.wobblycogs.co.uk/index.php/computing/javafx/145-editing-null-data-values-in-a-cell-with-javafx-2